# LED bulb flicker @ rate of 50 Hz or more

Tags: led, ac, triac, snubber

I am currently testing a 5W LED bulb (direct operating on 230V AC) switching using a Triac [BTA12-600B](https://www.rcscomponents.kiev.ua/datasheets/bta12-600b.pdf). I fed the signal from a microcontroller to an opto-triac coupler [MOC3041](http://kubuntu.free.fr/wiki/data/fp/moc3041.pdf). The LED bulb turns ON and OFF without any issues. 
Please note: I am using the LED only for ON/OFF purpose (no dimming).

Below is the working circuit.

[image: without snubber]

Now I add a snubber circuit in between just to protect my Triac in case of overvoltage. Below is the modified circuit

[image: with snubber]

Now comes one big issue:

**The LED bulb flickers repeatedly, think at the rate of 50Hz or more.** I am unaware of the internal circuitry the LED bulb has as it is enclosed in a retrofit case.

I feel, addition of snubber circuitry is causing the flicker because the LED bulb never flicker when I used the circuit without snubber.

Any reason why the LED flickers and its possible solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is energy hold-up in the LED bulb, not your triac dimmer. You can't solve it with a snubber.

Comment: Any idea how do i get rid of hold-up energy in LED bulb?

Comment: Get a bulb made för triac dimmers.

Comment: ...and get a dimmer made for LED bulbs..and compatible with the specific type you have. It's a bit of a dog's breakfast I'm afraid.

Comment: Please note that I am not dimming the LED bulb. Only ON/OFF

Comment: The BTA12-600B has Igt max of 50mA. The configuration you have with R2=4.7K does not give enough gate current. Rearrange the snubber and gate circuit.

Comment: @rioraxe: Igt max of 50mA. Does it mean that the minimum gate current required to turn ON the BTA12-600B ?

Comment: That is the amount of current that is guaranteed to turn on the triac.

Comment: @rioraxe: Probably i will remove the gate resistor of 470 ohms and see if the flicker goes. If not then would reduce the 4.7K to 2.2K resistor.

Comment: _"Now I add a snubber circuit in between just to protect my Triac in case of overvoltage."_ - How would a snubber protect from overvoltage?

Comment: @marcelm: snubber used to limit dv/dt, not overvoltage. Thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 1):

Your config seems a bit odd to me. You may try this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmJKia.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the snubber cap C1 may be 10n to 100nF.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will try the circuit you suggest and see if the issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the specifications of the led bulb. Not all led bulbs have do have dimmable electronics. There are many different situations and it can be hard to tell you if it works or not.

Example. Some inmitation carbon thread led bulbs can be dimmed. Others have the strange behaviour of dimming partly or not at all. Somethimes they start to flicker.

Advise. Before buying a ledbulb you have to ask yourself the question if you want to use a dimmer or just on/off switching. Then select the bulb accordingly. A good store advisor should be able to inform you correctly.

Comment: @ Decapod: I am using LED just for ON/OFF switching and not dimming. Yet i find flicker in LED when Traic is turned ON.

Comment: @gauravbhand Oh! That's a compleatly different issue! Please add this in your original question. You have too high hold-up current in your triac compared to your LED bulb consumption. Does it go away for now if you add more load in parallel?

Comment: @winny: I didn't try with more loads. Will arrange for more such 2-3 LEDs and check.

Comment: @winny: With same Triaccirc uit, but without snubber, the LED does not flicker. The flickering started after i added snubber circuit.

Comment: @gauravbhand You could be right on the ridge/threshold of minimum triac current and slightly reshape the current waveform to push you over the limit to start the flickering.

Comment: @winny: i will try with more loads.

Comment: @winny: i connected a 7W LED bulb in parallel with existing 5W LED. The flickering reduced drastically. Does it mean, the load current should be more than Igt max ?

Comment: @gauravbhand Igt max? Check the datasheet of the triac for minimum holding current. There are switchable ballast circuits to solve this problem, but finding a triac with even lower minimum holding current will probabaly be easier.

Comment: It might be possible to circumvent the whole problem by using an IGBT in a bridge rectifier!